# Problema con el renderizado de .map en React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Buen día a todos.
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en React Native, el problema que tengo es el siguiente:
En un pantalla 'padre', obtengo datos de una BD SQLite, una vez obtenidos los guardo en un estado.
Ej:

**Pantalla Principal**

```
const cargarEstado = () => 
{
  //Codigo donde se realiza la consulta de la BD
   
  setState(results);
}
```

Aquí ya tengo en mi estado el JSON que requiero, ejemplo: `[{producto: sabritas, precio: 3500.00, cantidad: 1}, {producto: leche, precio: 200.00, cantidad: 2}].`

Cuando se carga el estado, yo renderizo un componente.

```
return (
   <View>  
     {state.length > 0 && ({
    state.map((element, index) => (
      <ProductoCard
        producto={element}
        parentTotal={getTotal}
   )})}
   </View>
   )
```

A ProductoCard le mando como atributo getTotal, la idea es que cada que se renderice un ProductoCard se realice lo siguiente dentro del componente:

**ProductoCard**

```
 export default function ProductoCard({producto, getTotal}){
 
 useEffect(()=>{
    calcularTotal();
 },[]);

 const calcularTotal = () => {
  let total  = producto.precio * producto.cantidad;
  getTotal(total);
 }

}
```

Y así cada ProductoCard debería mandar a la Pantalla Principal el total de su producto, pero al momento de intentar guardar los esperados 2 valores dentro de un arreglo:

```
const getTotal = (value) => {
  let temp = [];
   temp.push(value);
   console.log(temp)
}
```

Pasa lo siguiente, el console.log me imprime esto:

```
temp [{3500}]
temp [{400}]
```

Al final temp se queda con el valor de [{400}], cuando lo que yo requiero es que se quede con `[{3500}, {400}]`.

Espero puedan ayudarme, llevo 3 días trabado con esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este componente

```
return (
   <View>  
     {state.length > 0 && ({
    state.map((element, index) => (
      <ProductoCard
        producto={element}
        parentTotal={getTotal}
   )})}
   </View>
   )
```

Agrega:

```javascript
useEffect(function(){
  if(state.length){
    console.log(state.map(item => item.producto.precio * item.producto.cantidad))
    // [ 400, 300 ]
    // Aqui puedes setear una variable setTotal()
    
    // Si quieres el valor total de todos los elementos
    // console.log(state.reduce(function(acc, item){
    //   return acc + (item.producto.precio * item.producto.cantidad)
    // }), 0)

    // Pero si tienes un [ total, setTotal ] (como te dije arriba)
    // console.log(total.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item, 0))
  }
}, [state])
```

Lo que estas haciendo es llamar una variable por cada elemento hijo, la cual solo conoce a su elemento hijo, nunca te va a dar el valor de otros elementos.

Comment: Hola Diego, gracias por tu comentario. El código que puse en esta pregunta es bastante simple para poner contexto de lo que pretendía hacer, en realidad, ProductoCard realiza mucho mas operaciones que la simple multiplicación. En conclusión, debo realizar todos esos cálculos en la pantalla principal, agradezco que me hayas aclarado la duda, ¡saludos!

Comment: Si obligatoriamente necesitas sacar los valores dentro de los hijos, tienes que pasar el array a cada hijo y hacer respectivos calculos. Por cierto, en tu codigo tienes esto: *parentTotal={getTotal}*... Si no me equivoco en el componente hijo llamas getTotal y no parentTotal... Ten cuidado!